# Dart equivalent of anonymous type object from TypeScript

Tags: typescript, flutter, dart

In TypeScript, I can simply define an anonymous object like below and still get intellisense for it.

```js
let person = {
  age: 10,
}
```

Unfortunately, I cannot able to do that same in the dart lang.

But I can do something similar using class and static properties.

```dart
class Person {
  static age = 10;
}
```

This gets the job done but I wonder if there are any simpler approach for this.

Comment: did you try  this  "var person = {"age" : 10};" ?

Comment: Yes, it did. My goal was to get IDE intellisense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Answer for Dart >= v3.0.0

Dart 3 introduces `Record`s, which allow you do what you want:

```dart
final person = (
  name: 'Foo',
  username: '@bar',
  age: 45,
  greet: () => 'Hello, Foo',
  greetIAm: (String iam) => 'Hello, Foo! I am $iam',
);

void main() {
  // Foo
  print(person.name);

  // @bar
  print(person.username);

  // 45
  print(person.age);

  // Hello Foo!
  print(person.greet());

  // Hello Foo! I am Bar!
  print(person.greetIAm('Bar!'));
}
```

You can also define types that declare the fields you want without the need to declare a new class:

```dart
typedef Person = ({
  String name,
  int age,
});

// With positional values instead:
typedef PersonButWithUnnamedParams = (
  String name,
  int age,
);

Person createPerson(String name, int age) {
  return (
    name: name,
    age: age,
  );
}

// Create a var direct from the type definitio.
final Person stranger = (
  age: -1,
  name: 'Stranger',
);

// Create a var of type Person through a function.
final Person stranger2 = createPerson('Stranger', -1);

// Positional params are also supported.
final PersonButWithUnnamedParams stranger3 = (
  'Stranger',
  -1,
);
```

Limitations:

- You can't reference a typedef recursively, you'll need to declare a class instead.

---

### Answer for Dart < v3.0.0

**You can't.**

Dart doesn't support anonymous types.

You can define a `Map`:

```dart
final person = <String, int>{'age': 10};
```

But in the intellisense perspective it is only a `Map` which contains keys of type `String` and values of type `int`, can't infer that there's a key `age` of value `10`

So you should define it as a class if you want intellisense:

```dart
class Person {
  const Person(this.age);

  final int age;
}

const person = Person(10);

print(person.age); // 10
```

Comment: This isn't related to strong typing.  Dart simply doesn't support *anonymous* types.  For example, the compiler could create a new type automatically, and then it would have the usual benefits of strong typing (e.g. not being able to assign it to variables of a different type).